# How to disable STUN or KILL function in Chinese radios?

Tags: ht, tyt

Many FM handheld and mobile radios employ "Stun sequence" and "Kill sequence" that can block the station TX or TX+RX functions after having received a specific DTMF code sequence over the air.

I would like to disable this dangerous function at all, or at least make sure my radio is not "stunned" or "killed" by a random sequence overheard over the air. BTW, exactly this happened recently to a friend of mine on his CRT Micron station...

Would you know how to ensure this, especially on TYT TH-UV98 and TH-UV99? Or, for that matter, on CRT-brand stations?

Comment: It seems you can program the sequence of DTMF digits that will kill, stun or restore the radio.

If the sequence is 5 digits or more, I think it is unlikely that someone else could guess or brute-force the correct code. At 2 seconds per guess it might take 12 hours, which would be very unusual activity on air.

Most important would be to change the codes away from the defaults.

Comment: @tomnexus this *actually* happened to a friend of mine. He messaged me that his Micron was "stunned", asking "what is it?" He wasn't aware that such function existed before this happened. The radio was bought brand new but the retailer refuses to take any responsibility claiming "you did it to yourself". I googled and downloaded a PDF looking as manual for this model and it states that the **factory default** of Stun code is "123456". My guess is his radio somehow "overheard" someone randomly trying sending DTMF numbers and unfortunately it was just this 123456 sequence (not so unlikely).

Comment: P.S. I found the same trap in my TYT TH-UV98. But I deleted both the stun code and the kill code completely to avoid this kind of event.